# PHP Autoload Class From Namespace

Tags: php, object-oriented

I wrote this function to be passed as a param in `spl_autoload_register()`. It autoloads PHP classes from their respective directories using their namespace, named the same as path. I am not sure if there would be any easier way but this is quite simple and does what it needs to.

```
spl_autoload_register(function($class) {
    $ns = explode('\\', strtolower($class));
    $class = array_pop($ns);
    $ns = implode('\\', $ns) . '\\';
    require_once __DIR__ . '\\' .  $ns . 'class.' . $class . '.php';
});
```

Thoughts on this? Is there an easier way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your namespaces match your directory structure you would not need to fetch the class name. You could just append it to the base path and append the `.php` file extension.

I would argue the `class.` file prefix is unnecessary. I think of such prefixes from a time when namespaces was not available. If you are concerned with the ease of locating correct files I can recommend the following method. I have used for several projects and are quite happy with it.

```
classes/
    interfaces/
        interfaceName.php
    abstracts/
    traits/
    class.php
    anotherclass.php
```

I hope you get the idea. If you follow this you can use this.

```
spl_autoload_register(function($class) {

    $filename = __DIR__ . '\\' . $class . '.php';

    if(!file_exists($filename)) {
        return false; // End autoloader function and skip to the next if available.
    }

    include $filename;
    return true; // End autoloader successfully.

});
```

This is pretty much it. You should of course check that `__DIR__` equals your base path. If you store your base path inside a variable and you are using a closure as callback, you can inject the path into the closure using this:

```
$path = 'This is your base path.';

spl_autoload_register(function($class) use ($path) {...});
```

If your file system uses forward-slashes (for some reason), you could wrap the `$class` variable in a `str_replace()` function call.

```
$class = str_replace('\\', '/', $class);
```

Happy coding!

Comment: This is answer is a good answer, as it reviews the code. But, not reinventing the wheel but using standards that exist should be the proper solution as Alex L points out in his answer

Comment: I would argue the "standards" are only useful for projects that existed before namespaces. If you take all that away you remain with this. I understand your comment, but I took a point in the OP code.

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks fairly good. It's nice and easy to comprehend, and it's to the point. It is also something that's been done before, so luckily you can look at others' code and compare/contrast.

I'd like to suggest looking at the [FIG standard autoloader](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-4-autoloader-examples.md). It comes from this [PHP FIG Autoloader standards page](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/), which is an excellent resource when determining what looks "good."

Also, you may want to take a look at other, maintained autoloaders, such as [the Aura Autoloader](https://github.com/auraphp/Aura.Autoload). If you choose not to use it, it could still give you hints on how to expand/improve your current code.

---

If I could improve your code, I'd recommend the following:

- Expand `$ns` to `$namespace`, just for completeness.
- I would check to make sure your file exists; if it doesn't, an error may be raised which is something you don't want.